# ObjectiveC test if int is long or not / CGFloat is float or double

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

Apple now requires all iOS code to be 32/64 bit dualistic. That's great - except there's a few of their libraries that don't fully support the duality.

e.g. one project uses NSScanner, which supports "scanInteger" (correct) but no "scanCGFloat" - instead you have to "scanFloat" or "scanDouble" (encoded in the method names!).

---

UPDATE: NSScanner is a nastier example than I realised; it takes pointers as args.

```
- (BOOL)scanFloat:(float *)result;
- (BOOL)scanDouble:(double *)result;
```

...ugh.

---

It affects a whole bunch of stuff - another example is math.h (similarly: float vs double is encoded in function names), although there you can at least switch to tgmath.h and get rid of the "type-is-in-the-name" silliness.

What's the correct, general, solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you mean: `if (sizeof(int) == sizeof(long))`?

Comment: Yep, c.f. below that's currently my best idea - but this will leave the compiler complaining forever :(

Comment: You should file a bug report asking for a new -scanCGFloat: method.

Comment: @GregParker sort-of; the thing is, I can understand why they DIDN'T add it: it would create a dependency on Quartz/CoreGraphics, outside of the Quartz framework. All the methods inside the framework use CGFloat - but the ones outside (like NSScanner) have this problem. I think what they really need is an NSFloat, maybe? :)

Comment: This short of thing is frequently added by a category. For example, AppKit/UIKit could implement a category that adds -scanCGFloat:, because it already depends on CoreGraphics.

Comment: @gregparker - very good point. I guess there isnt really a justification for this - its a bug, something Apple probably just didnt notice when they were updatig the other libs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C11 has introduced a new feature "Generic selection" that can be used to 
let the compiler choose the right method, depending on the type of `CGFloat`.

Written as a `NSScanner` category method:

```
@implementation NSScanner (MyCategory)

-(BOOL) myScanCGFloat:(CGFloat *)cgFloatValue
{
    return _Generic(*cgFloatValue,
                    double: [self scanDouble:(double *)cgFloatValue],
                    float: [self scanFloat:(float *)cgFloatValue]);
}

@end
```

Remarks:

- The `_Generic` keyword is described in "6.5.1.1 Generic selection" of the C11 standard (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Another description is here:
  http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html.
- Selecting the matching code is done by the *compiler*, not at runtime.
- The selection checks if `CGFloat` is compatible to `float` or `double`,
  not if the current target architecture is 32-bit or 64-bit.
- This solution does not depend on any preprocessor macros.
- As of Xcode 5.0.2, Clang supports the `_Generic` keyword, even in the default GNU99 mode. I have not tested earlier Xcode/Clang versions.

---

***Previous answer:*** One possible solution would be do mimic the definition of `CGFloat`
and let the preprocessor choose the correct version:

```
CGFloat f;

#if __LP64__
    [scanner scanDouble:&f];
#else
    [scanner scanFloat:&f];
#endif
```

Or you define a custom macro:

```
#if __LP64__
#define scanCGFloat scanDouble
#else
#define scanCGFloat scanFloat
#endif

// ...
CFFloat f;
[scanner scanCGFloat:&f];
```

Alternatively, use a temporary variable:

```
double tmp;
[scanner scanDouble:&tmp];
f = tmp;
```

Comment: NB: Using a temporary variable isn't viable - scanFloat: takes a pointer for good reason (in my experience: it's often called literally hundreds-of-thousands of times in any single parse)

Comment: LP_64 looks the right kind of solution - but I was hoping for something simpler. The CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE constant I found in Apple's headers seems to be the "intended" version of LP_64, for this set of use-cases - what do you think? (I can't find any documentation mentioning it though :( )

Comment: @Adam: CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE looks OK, I had not noticed that before your posting. To be on the safe side, you can check with `#ifdef CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE ... #else #error "CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE is undefined" #endif`.

Comment: @Adam: I have updated with a new suggestion that does not rely on any preprocessor macros.

Comment: Wow. Generic selection is AWESOME!

Answer (score 1):

For reference (and I feel this is a poor, cludgy solution), my best idea so far is to do:

NB -- I'm using NSScanner as an example, but it's a general problem/solution!

```
if( sizeof( var ) <= 4 )
    [scanner scanFloat:&var];
else
    [scanner scanDouble:&var];
```

...but this will NOT fix the compiler-errors (on both platforms), it'll simply make it "do the right thing at runtime" as a hack. Surely not a good solution?

Comment: Why not just `scanDouble:` and then convert it to a `CGFloat`? That way, you surely don't loose any precision.

Comment: Apple's own design is that CGFloat is often a member of a struct. NSScanner uses pointers specifically so that you can write directly into structs. If you don't, with parsing you can easily get 10x performance drops on iOS (worst culprit: recursive parsing). Obviously you should avoid recursive parsing with temp variables - but it's common in a lot of code I come across!

Comment: So, e.g. ... to fill a { CGPoint, CGPoint, CGSize, CGFloat, CGFloat } struct that represents geometry of (say) a CALayer ... NSScanner will do this efficiently, even if you're delegating to different methods to fill out the different parts.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, routing around in headers, I just found this (NOT mentioend in Apple's official "upgrade to 64bit" docs!!!)

> #define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
>
> #define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 0

...so I guess this is the thing to use?

Comment: In that vein, you could add a category onto `NSScanner` with a `-scanCGFloat:` method that simply calls `-scanDouble:` or `-scanFloat:`…I guess Martin's answer is kind of similar.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to scan as a double and then cast the result to CGFloat.

```
-(CGFloat) scanCGFloat
{

    double myDouble;
    [scanner scanDouble: &myDouble];
    return (CGFloat) myDouble;
}
```

Use a similar trick for NSInteger and NSUInteger, always scan as a (unsigned) long and cast to NS(U)Integer.

Comment: As I already noted: this is not a solution. Using additional storage space BREAKS the API - there's very very good reason why the API takes a pointer.

Comment: @Adam:  wrong.  The API `-scanDouble:` expects a pointer to a double and my solution gives it a pointer to a double.  The solution is clean and correct.  Try it.

Comment: Take a CGRect, and scanDouble into it. How are you going to do this? It's not about the type you take, it's about changing an API call designed to use zero storage .. into one that requires storage :(

Comment: @Adam You don't scanDouble into a CGRect, you scanDouble into a double and then assign the appropriate member of the CGRect from that double.  What do you care about it using an extra 8 bytes on the stack?

Comment: With iOS today, that 8 bytes balloons after about 5 iterative steps and grows exponentially on each recursion. Call it a bug (or performance optimization "gone wrong") in live iOS - but IMHO its fair enough that tight inner loops that are expected to recurse heavily (ie scanning / parsing) should be using constant memory allocation.

Comment: @Adam The eight bytes are on the stack.  When the function exits, the storage used is automatically "freed" by the stack frame unwinding.

Comment: that's disingenuous in the extreme - a stack allocation is still an allocation, and you can still (easily) run out of memory from doing too much of it, especially on lower-memory devices (as shipped by Apple). Even so, this is ObjectiveC, not C, so we're talking about more than stack frames - message-sending is implemented with a bit more complexity and overhead. Finally: I'm not makign this up, it's all easily verifiable in Instruments: recursive functions in current ObjC do strange things after a certain depth.

Comment: @Adam No, what is disingenuous is pretending that a method that is not recursively called that uses 8 bytes on the stack can cause stack overflow. Message sending is implemented as a function that looks up the method for the selector in a hash table and then jumps to the beginning of the method.  Still only one stack frame.

Comment: why don't you try it, instead of ignoring everything I say, and claiming "that won't happen" - even though it does? As I've said: I've verified this multiple times, as have others, on different machines, different iOS versions, different devices.

Comment: @Adam Because I've used it before and I know it doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: @Adam I think we must be talking at cross purposes, because this is basic stuff.  I've modified the code in my answer to more explicitly reflect what I am saying.  Take a look at it and then tell me how you think it could possibly cause a stack overflow.

Comment: I misunderstood, yes - sorry, my fault. There is a real problem with Apple's allocation of temp variables inside deeply nested loops - but I have NOT tested for the case you're describing (I got confused between what you were saying and what I'd tried, sorry).

Comment: No need to apologise.  I should have been more explicit in my original post.