# What is most common and correct practice to get a CGFloat from an NSNumber?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The working code for me is something like:

```
NSNumber *n = @42.42;
CGFloat cgf = 0; 
CFNumberRef cfn = CFBridgingRetain(n);
CFNumberGetValue(cfn, kCFNumberCGFloatType, &cgf);
CFRelease(cfn);
```

There could be also

```
CGFloat cgf = (CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE) ? [n doubleValue] : [n floatValue];
```

But this smells even uglier for me.

It seems to me there should be better API for doing such a common thing. Are there any?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will get the correct result in any case:

```
 NSNumber *n = @42.42;
 CGFloat cgf = [n doubleValue];
```

because `CGFloat` is either `float` or `double`.

---

`NSNumber` does not have a `CGFloatValue` method. You could define one
using the toll-free bridge to `CFNumberRef`:

```
@interface NSNumber (MyCGFloatValue)
-(CGFloat)myCGFloatValue;
@end

@implementation NSNumber (MyCGFloatValue)
-(CGFloat)myCGFloatValue{
    CGFloat result;
    CFNumberGetValue((__bridge CFNumberRef)(self), kCFNumberCGFloatType, &result);
    return result;
}
@end
```

or using the C11 feature "Generic selection", where the *compiler* chooses the appropriate
code depending on the type of `CGFloat`:

```
@implementation NSNumber (MyCGFloatValue)
-(CGFloat)myCGFloatValue{
    CGFloat result;
    result = _Generic(result,
            double: [self doubleValue],
            float: [self floatValue]);
    return result;
}
@end
```

And then

```
NSNumber *n = @42.24;
CGFloat f = [n myCGFloatValue];
```

but I doubt that it is worth the hassle.

Comment: @rounak: Thanks. Actually in this particular case it does not offer much advantage over `CGFloat cgf = [n doubleValue];`, but when you *scan* a CGFloat then it helps to avoid a temporary variable, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731828/objectivec-test-if-int-is-long-or-not-cgfloat-is-float-or-double.

Answer (score 4):

Just always get the double value. If CGFloat is only a ‘float’ on your machine the double will be instantly truncated, so you don’t care.

Answer (score 1):

The older answers are both correct. Just for my 2¢, here's my implementation:

```
@implementation NSNumber (TypeConversion)

- (CGFloat)cgFloatValue
{
#if CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE
    return self.doubleValue;
#else
    return self.floatValue;
#endif
}

@end
```

---

This relies on the definition of `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE` in CGBase.h for Objective C, or CoreGraphics.h for Swift:

```
// Don't write this code; it's already included in Foundation :)

#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE double
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
# define CGFLOAT_MIN DBL_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX DBL_MAX
#else
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 0
# define CGFLOAT_MIN FLT_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX FLT_MAX
#endif

typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;
#define CGFLOAT_DEFINED 1
```

<sup>From [CoreGraphics.h](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/82509cbd7451e72fb99d22556ad259ceb335cb1f/test/Inputs/clang-importer-sdk/usr/include/CoreGraphics.h)</sup>